# Counterexample of convex property

Tags: calculus, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I have studied a property in my textbook which establishes that, given $\emptyset \neq X \subset \mathbb{R} ^ n $ and $\alpha \in [0,1]$,$X \subset (1-\alpha)X+\alpha X$, whose proof is evident since the set
$$(1-\alpha)X+\alpha X=\{y \in \mathbb{R} ^ n| y=(1-\alpha) x+\alpha x, x\in X\} $$ and then
$$x_0 \in X \Rightarrow (1-\alpha)x_0+\alpha x_0=x_0$$.
In addition, the double inclusion it is guaranteed when $X$ is a convex set. But in general it is not guaranteed and I am trying to find a counterexample for it. My intuition says a sphere may work but I can't see really how to formalize it. Aprreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, take sphere and try $(1-\alpha)x + \alpha y$ for absolutely any $ x \not = y \in S^{n-1}$. For simplicity try $x, -x$.

Comment: I'm not sure what is being claimed here. The equation on the right hand side of the implication appears to be an identity. Should all the $x_0$s be $x_0$?

Comment: Let $X$ be two distinct points. Then write their midpoint as a combination with $\apha = 1/2$,

Comment: By reading the comments, I think I was mistaken. So, when considering an element of the set $(1-\alpha) X+\alpha X$, for example, if $x,y \in X$ with $x \neq y$, then $(1-\alpha)x+\alpha y \in (1-\alpha) X+\alpha X$? That is to say, it is not necessary to take the same element in $X$ to obtain the correspondant element in $(1-\alpha) X+\alpha X$. Is this right?

Comment: In this way, $(1-\alpha) X + \alpha X=\{y \in \mathbb{R}^n | y=(1-\alpha)x_1+\alpha x_2 \forall x_1,x_2 \in X\}$

Comment: @CharlesJA I'm still not really certain what your question is about, but no, you don't need to necessarily choose $x \neq y$. Your second characterisation of $(1 - \alpha)X + \alpha X$ is correct, and indeed, for any $x \in X$, $x = (1 - \alpha)x + \alpha x \in (1 - \alpha)X + \alpha X$. That is, $X$ is a subset of this new set.